# INSERT INTO varchar by python

Tags: python, postgresql

I tried to `insert INTO table` via python and I still got this error: using windows 10

```
cr = con.cursor()
cr.execute('''
CREATE TABLE table1(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR NOT NULL

);

''')
cr.execute('INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,'ahmad');')

con.commit()
con.colse()
cr.close()
```

and i got this message:

```
> File "c:/Users/acer/test/gh.py", line 19 cr.execute('INSERT INTO
> table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,'ahmad');') ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cr.execute('INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,'ahmad');')
```

You should use " and ' otherwise python thinks you are closing single quotes writing ahmad and open single quotes again.

```
cr.execute("INSERT INTO table1 (id,name) VALUES (1,'ahmad');")
```